# Bundle not get activated after installing to Pax-Exam container

Tags: osgi, pax-exam

I am installing an OSGi bundle to the Pax-Exam Container in a test class , Following is my code segment.

```
@Configuration
public Option[] config() {

    return options(
 mavenBundle().artifactId("sample-bundle").groupId("org.sample.code").versionAsInProject(),
```

I have a service registration in my bundle Activator as follows for the above sample-bundle.

```
bundleContext.registerService(TestCode.class.getName(), testClassInstance, null);
```

After debugging the test case , found that above bundle is not activated  (State Number 32) and it's in resolved state (State number 4). However after I removing the above service registration from the start() method of the bundle, bundle got activated successfully.

Any idea what went wrong here?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is an exception in the Activator. Often these errors are not shown in the log. Use a try catch around it and lot the exception.
Besides that I found that you sometimes get a better error message by grabbing and starting your bundle in the test case.

Comment: Yeah. Thats the case. I have to set some settings before provision the bundle. Is there any annotation I can achieve that?.. call a setup method before calling the @configuration annotation?..

Comment: That depends a bit on what you need to setup. Can you clarify what you need to provide?

Comment: Had to setup some, environment variables, system properties etc.. These are necessary for he activation of the bundle. I called a method, in the configuration before doing the provisioning. It's working at the moment, but not sure the correct thing to do.